# How do I use \fnsymbol in an enumerate label

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

Here's what I've got. For some reason when I use fnsymbol I'm not getting anything, no error messages either. I'm trying to get two diamond shapes, followed by a space, followed by the fnsymbol.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem,xcolor}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textcolor{blue}{\roman{enumi}.)}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textcolor{yellow}{\roman{enumi}-
\arabic{enumii}}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\textcolor{red}{\alph{enumiii}/\roman{enumi}-
\arabic{enumii}}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\textcolor{green}{$\diamond\diamond$ 
\fnsymbol{enumiv}}}
```

This is what I get when I try it like this. I've already tried it without the diamonds, but I get the same result. I'm thinking that I may be missing a package,  but I can't figure out what that would be. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: compiled pdf with fnsymbol missing]

Comment: Why are you using `\renewcommand{enumi...}` when `enumitem` is in action. Also provide a compilable document, not just fragments only

Comment: The enumeration style is weird ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\fnsymbol` tries to expand the `enumiv` prematurely, at a 'time' when `enumiv` still has the value `0`, which leads to zero output of `\fnsymbol`,  so `\protect\fnsymbol` is a possible way to ensure that `\fnsymbol{enumiv}` (which is basically the content to be displayed) has the correct output.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textcolor{blue}{\roman{enumi}.)}}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textcolor{yellow}{\roman{enumi}-
%\arabic{enumii}}}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\textcolor{red}{\alph{enumiii}/\roman{enumi}-
%\arabic{enumii}}}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\textcolor{green}{$\diamond\diamond$ 
%\fnsymbol{enumiv}}}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={{\color{blue}\roman*.)}}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={{\color{yellow}\roman{enumi}-\arabic*}}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label={{\color{red}\alph*/\roman{enumi}-\arabic{enumiii}}}}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label={{\color{green}$\diamond\diamond$\protect\fnsymbol{enumiv}}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}


  \item Erste Ebene
  \item Erste Ebene mit darunterliegender Ebene
    \begin{enumerate} 
      \item Zweite Ebene
            \begin{enumerate} 
            \item Dritte Ebene
              \begin{enumerate} 
              \item Vierte Ebene
              \item Vierte Ebene wiederholt 
            \end{enumerate}
          \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

A way with `\AddEnumerateCounter` to enable `enumitem` to use `\fnsymbol*`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\makeatletter
% Provide a \fnsymbol way for the `*` style of enumitem
\AddEnumerateCounter{\fnsymbol}{\@fnsymbol}{2}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={{\color{blue}\roman*.)}}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={{\color{yellow}\roman{enumi}-\arabic*}}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label={{\color{red}\alph*/\roman{enumi}-\arabic{enumiii}}}}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label={{\color{green}$\diamond\diamond$\fnsymbol*}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Erste Ebene
  \item Erste Ebene mit darunterliegender Ebene
    \begin{enumerate} 
      \item Zweite Ebene
        \item Mehr von der 2. Ebene
            \begin{enumerate} 
            \item Dritte Ebene
              \begin{enumerate} 
              \item Vierte Ebene 
              \item Vierte Ebene wiederholt
            \end{enumerate}
          \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Codepod: Grüße nach Österreich ;-)